# load more rows in listactivity in android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, listactivity

what i am implementing ListActivity with custom row.
I am wondering if there id any possibility to load more rows when the listview reaches the bottom .
I have found this tutorial [Endless scrolling in listview](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

Please help me understand how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` allows you to register an `OnScrollListener`. It's `onScroll`-Method gets called everytime the user scrolls in the ListView. By doing some calculations with the parameters provided, you can check whether the user reached the end of the ListView. To quote some code from your example:

```
if (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
   // we are less or equal to visibleThreshold items away from the end      
}
```

There, you can just load some more items from wherever you get them, put them into your Adapter and call it's `notifyDataSetChanged()`-Method. Make sure you call that method from your UI-Thread though, for example by using the `runOnUiThread`-Method of your Activity.

Comment: I used ListActivity to implement my list, and i didn't notice that it has its own ListView that i have only to set my custom onscrolllistner as  its onscrollListner. Thanks anyway